# OneToMany mapping in JPA , the ID value is not available to the Second level child objects

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Before i head to my question, Let me brief my code:

```
@Entity
```

`public class GrandParent{
PrimaryKey : GrandParentId`

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH })
    @JoinColumn(name = "GrandParent_ID", referencedColumnName = "GrandParent_ID", foreignKey = @javax.persistence.ForeignKey(name = "none", value = ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT)) @Where(clause = "ACTIVE = 1 ")
    private final List<Parent> parents = new ArrayList<Parent>();}   




 @Entity 
public class Parent
{

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH })
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "Parent_ID", referencedColumnName = "Parent_ID", foreignKey = @javax.persistence.ForeignKey(name = "none", value = ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT)),
            @JoinColumn(name = "GrandParent_ID", referencedColumnName = "GrandParent_ID", foreignKey = @javax.persistence.ForeignKey(name = "none", value = ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT))    })

private final List<Child> childs= new ArrayList<Child>();
```

....
}

@Entitypublic class Child
{
PrimaryKey : ChildId`
}

Here when i try to save/ or call Save on GrandParent Entity all its associated children are getting saved but the  grandParentId which needs to be populated in child entity is coming as 0.0 .

So my question is: Is there any way where i can cascade the primary id value of grandParent Entity down to Child Entity through any anno

Comment: Format your code correctly and you might get some answers.

Comment: Why exactly do you need grandparent to be directly available in child? Seems redundant

Comment: I just need the primary Key value of GrandParent entity to be auto updated  in Child column grandparentId when we save , Is there any way i can achieve this through associations is my question.